# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory for amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so

Tags: php, memcached, centos7, amazon-elasticache

i keep getting these php warning when executing systemctl restart php-fpm

```
[23-Apr-2019 09:54:12] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so' (tried: /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so (/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied), /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so.so (/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Apr 23 09:54:12 ip-10-2-2-171 systemd[1]: Started The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
```

on the ec2 machine, memcached and session are configured correctly,

```
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/session.ini,
igbinary session support => yes
memcache.session_prefix_host_key => 0 => 0
memcache.session_prefix_host_key_remove_subdomain => 0 => 0
memcache.session_prefix_host_key_remove_www => 1 => 1
memcache.session_prefix_static_key => no value => no value
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2
memcache.session_save_path => no value => no value
memcached.sess_binary_protocol => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_lock_expire => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5 => 5
memcached.sess_lock_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 2000 => 2000
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 1000 => 1000
memcached.sess_locking => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_persistent => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => no value => no value
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_sasl_password => no value => no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username => no value => no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit => 0 => 0
session
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => memcached => memcached
session.save_path => xxxx.cfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com => xxxx.cfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
```

but accessing this from info.php on the website, it seems the `session.save_path` and `session.save_handler` are being over written

any advise on how to troubleshoot this is much appreciated.